# What am I doing wrong with this powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm going mad here. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this - be it a scoping issue or some other PowerShell Nuance, and I can't believe I'm asking here, but I need help!

```
function test2() {
    write-host "asdf1"
    $test1=@{}
    $test1.Add("User1", "12345")
    $test1.Add("User2", "123455")
    $test1.Add("User3", "1234567")
    $test1
    Write-Host "asdf2"

}

function createUser($userName) {

    $test=@{}
    $test.Add("User1", "12345")
    $test.Add("User2", "123455")
    $test.Add("User3", "1234567")
    $test

    $token = test2
}
```

Let's say I have the above code in Power Shell.

If I call the createUser function like so:

createUser 12345

I get the following output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
User1                          12345
User3                          1234567
User2                          123455
asdf1
asdf2
```

Why does the hash table in the test2 function not output? It doesn't seem to work at all? What am I doing wrong here?

I've done some experimenting with this and honestly can't see why this doesn't work.

If I call test2 OUTSIDE of the createUser function, it works:

```
asdf1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
User1                          12345
User3                          1234567
User2                          123455
asdf2
```

Comment: You're assigning the output from `test2` to `$token` but then never outputting that variable

Answer (score 0):

As Santiago Squarzon says, the line `$token = test2` is capturing the output in the variable `$token`, that's why it is not seen. Change the code to:

```
function test2() {
    write-host "asdf1"
    $test1=@{}
    $test1.Add("User1", "12345")
    $test1.Add("User2", "123455")
    $test1.Add("User3", "1234567")
    $test1
    Write-Host "asdf2"

}

function createUser($userName) {

    $test=@{}
    $test.Add("User1", "12345")
    $test.Add("User2", "123455")
    $test.Add("User3", "1234567")
    $test

    test2    # <--- this
}
```